# Zurb Foundation multiple stylesheets (compass)

Tags: sass, compass-sass, zurb-foundation

I've created a project with compass+foundation
I have multiple .scss on my page and I want to use foundation mixins in all of them.
If I do the import settings, import foundation. It copies all the settings in each files, which is taking a lot of unnecessary space. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use Foundation's mixins in your own scss files you should indeed use the @import directive. However you shouldn't import the *foundation.scss* file.

> Sass has a naming convention for files that are meant to be imported
>   (called “partials”): they begin with an underscore.

Only import the partials you need (I would be surprised that you need every single one).

For example I needed to use the "css-triangle" mixin from _foundation-global.scss  in one of my files.

```
MyStyles.scss

@import "../foundation/foundation-global"; (no need for the leading underscore)

.myClass{
   @include css-triangle(5px, #fff, top);
}
```

I'm sure you have read [this](http://sass-lang.com/tutorial.html), but I'll put the link just in case.